# Counting variable by day and time with day and time in column header

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to write a query that gives a count of purchases grouped by day and hour (from variable of date and time of purchase).

However, column headers should contain the date and hour as such:

| ID | Tuesday, 11-12 | Tuesday, 12-13 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xxxxx | 4 | 6 |
| Xxxxx | 1 | 8 |

Variables include ID, Date of purchase (DD-MM-YY timestamp), QTY

Having done some reading, I am not entirely convinced this is possible? But am unsure and could be misinformed.

Thanks for your help in advance. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Its possible from a table with 3 columns like you mentioned (id, datetime, qty). Not really sure on the variable part, perhaps if you can provide more details on how those variables are getting populated.

Comment: mysql and snowflake are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Which one do you use?

Comment: Btw, this seems to be dynamic pivoting problem. It is possible to do this in mysql using sql only (for mysql this would be a duplicate question, no clue about snowflake), however you really should do this transformation in some kind of a BI software, like Tableau or Power BI.

Comment: @Shadow ah I see, apologies very new to this. Appreciate the advice. Queries would be executed in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can solve this with the PIVOT clause.  Derive the unique dates you want in the query, then use PIVOT to put across into columns.  I'd provide an example but I don't have the time this moment.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the advice